# How to merge multiple output and store in a single variable

Tags: php, arrays

How can i merge the following output as a single row and store in a single variable

I have the following output

```
        THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-10
        THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-7
        THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-8
        THICKNESS: 10ItemID: VSG-22
        THICKNESS: 10ItemID: VSG-23
        THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-3
        THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-6
        THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-4
        THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-27
```

Here is the code i used to get the above output

```
        $d = explode(',', $row['ItemDesc']);
        $c = explode(',', $row['ItemIDgroup']);
           foreach($d as $k => $v)
            {
                 $d2 = explode(' ',$v); 
                 $output = "THICKNESS: " . $d2[1] ."ItemID: ". $c[$k];
                 echo $output;
                 echo"<br/>";
             }
```

I want to end up like and want to store in a single variable

```
   THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-10, THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-7,THICKNESS: .1875ItemID: VSG-8, ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you could just add the intended string to an array.

```
$final[] = "THICKNESS" . $row["ItemDesc"] . "ItemID: " . $row["ItemIDgroup"];
```

Then at the end just do `$output = implode(', ', $final);`